# MSSQL: How to add a column with a sum of three others

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE IDU = 406536063) as 'col1',
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) as 'col2',
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) as 'col3'
```

How can I add in MSSQL the forth column with the sum of values in `col1`, `col2`, `col3`?

Comment: Those are *three* queries combined by a `SELECT`. They take 3 times as long as each individual queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also move the queries to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, (col1 + col2 + col3)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as col1 FROM Table1 WHERE IDU = 406536063) t1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as col2 FROM Table2 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) t2 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as col3 FROM Table3 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) t3;
```

Although I do use subqueries in the `SELECT`, I usually put them in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Using cte might help:

```
;with cte (col1,col2,col3) as
(
   SELECT 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE IDU = 406536063) as 'col1',
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) as 'col2',
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE CustomerNr = 406536063) as 'col3'
)
select col1+col2+col3
from cte
```